# Textarea POSTing NULL when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I am saving a load of information to a database, and using jQuery to alert either a success or fail message, followed by clearing the form so the user can input a new set of data without leaving the page.
My textarea posts a NULL value when I use the jQuery script, but works perfectly when I don't use the script. All other inputs in the form work just fine, and changing the text area to an input type = text also works.

```
<form name = "usemarkscheme" id = "usemarkscheme" method ="POST" action ="submitmarks.php">
<a few inputs here that all work>
<textarea name = "add" placeholder = "Enter additional comments here"></textarea>
</form>
```

This is the jQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#submit").click(function () {
        $.post($("#usemarkscheme").attr("action"), $("#usemarkscheme: input").serializeArray(), function (data) {
            if (data === "This student has already received a mark for this mark scheme!") {
                alert("This student has already received a mark for this mark scheme!");
            } else {
                alert("Marks entered");
            }
        }
        //close $.post                
        );

        $("#usemarkscheme").submit(function () {
            return false;
        })

        //close onclick       function

        //clear form after every student has been marked
        $("#usemarkscheme").each(function () {
            this.reset();
        });
    });
});
```

The error messages work well

Comment: A little note to say instead of listening for the click on the submit button, you can just include the $.post() in your listener for the form submit. And if you wish, instead of using `return false;`, you can pass the event into the submit callback function and use event.preventDefault().

Comment: `$.post($("#usemarkscheme").attr("action"), $("#usemarkscheme: input").serializeArray(),$("textarea#myarea").val() function (data) {
            //your conditions
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
$("#usemarkscheme: input").serializeArray()
```

is fetching only the input fields. Try adding the textarea selector too. Try using

```
$("#usemarkscheme input, #usemarkscheme textarea").serializeArray()
```

or even better

```
$("#usemarkscheme").serializeArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simply problem is you use `$("#usemarkscheme: input")` and this will give you only input fealds not the textarea.

If im not wrong you have to try `$("#usemarkscheme: input, #usemarkscheme textarea")`